# ANSI escape codes not functioning when I printf them in x86 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, io, x86, printf, nasm

I am trying to make a simple x86 assembly program (I am using NASM as my assembler) that uses ANSI codes to change the terminal text color to red, then print something that will then be printed with a red foreground. The code is as follows:

```
; This macro is equivalent to printf(message)
%macro  print   1
        lea     rdi,    [rel %1]
        call    _printf
%endmacro
; Example call:
;   print    prompt
; Where prompt is something like:
;   prompt:
;       db      "Hiya dude! What's your name?", 0

; These are the terminal colors, they are ANSI codes that, when printed, will change the color of the text.
    section .data
COLOR_FORE_RED:
    db       "\033[31m",0 ; ANSI Fore Red code

%define  SetColor_FRed      print    COLOR_FORE_RED
```

But when I try to use these macros using something like:

```
SetColorFRed ; Set text color
print Hello  ; Print "Hello!:
section .data
Hello:
    db "Hello!",0
```

The output is:

```
\033[31mHello!  <- Output color is plain old black, not red
```

Why is it not changing the text color to red? As far as I can tell, this code is equivalent to using `printf("\033[31m Hiya!")` in C, which works perfectly fine on my computer and does change the output color to red. My platform is Mac OSX, I am programming in 64 bit x86, and I am running a Intel Core i7 processor.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Wow! Thank you! The backticks work for me, and the color is now red. (Haven't tried the octal option) mind posting your comment as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*NASM* doesn't process strings between double quotes <kbd>"</kbd> as *C* style strings. This means that *C* escape sequences like `\033`, `\n` etc are not specially treated and are emitted literally. *NASM* can interpret a *C* style string if you place the string between backticks <kbd>`</kbd> rather than double quotes.

Modify:

```
db       "\033[31m",0 ; ANSI Fore Red code
```

To be:

```
db       `\033[31m`,0 ; ANSI Fore Red code
```

This information can be found in the [*NASM* documentation](http://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html) under section *3.4.2 Character String*

---

*YASM* (a *NASM* like assembler) doesn't support backticks in this way. The alternative that works for *NASM* and *YASM* is to break the string up and emit the required escape sequence `\033` separately with something like:

```
db       33o, "[31m",0 ; ANSI Fore Red code
```

This emits the byte with a value of octal 33 followed by the rest of the string. Values with a suffix `o` are treated as octal values. This method should work with both *YASM* and *NASM*

Comment: if writing it as ordinary value, I would rather use `27` instead of `33o`, because I simply recall that "27" is "escape" in ASCII, I don't see any particular benefit in using octal form? Is it some ANSI control codes common?

Comment: @ped7g : I'm using octal because that is how the OP presented it in their string. I'm actually more partial to `1b` in hex for Escape since that is how I first saw the Escape character represented back in the very early 80s. Some people like the decimal value 27. Pick your poison. However for ANSI control sequences \033 in octal form is quite prevalent way of representing it (or \e`)